# Unable to perform module to module communication in Azure Edge

Tags: python, c#, azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I was trying to achieve module to module communication on Azure edge from c# module to python module,

```
Using Ubuntu as OS 
Edge Runtime: 1.0.8 
EdgeAgent 1.0.10 
EdgeHub 1.0.10
```

The c# code where the data is being sent

```
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: [{cloudtoDeviceMessages}]"); // cloudtoDeviceMessages is a string 

            await moduleClient.SendEventAsync("serialmoduleoutput", new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cloudtoDeviceMessages)));

            Console.WriteLine("Sent The Method Body To Serial Module");
```

The Routes in the deployment file, I have other modules routes as well, but only giving the relevant one

```
Fromc2dcommunicationmoduleToTestModule": "FROM /messages/modules/c2dcommunicationmodule/outputs/serialmoduleoutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/TestModule/inputs/input1\")",
```

Python Code: it's the same as this GitHub example https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/sync-samples/receive_message_on_input.py

In C# Code I am not getting any exception, how ever in the python module I am not getting any data either.

Comment: Is there anything in the receiving module's logs that might be useful? Or perhaps the edgeAgent logs in case the receiving module is crashing. It could be useful to include your deployment file as well.

Comment: Ok I will include the logs for edge Agent, Hub, and deployment file also

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by updating the azure-iot-device package in the requirement.txt file, by default on module creation it installs the package with the 2.0.0 version, but the latest version is 2.8. in the latest version communication is working fine.